# I am not able to connect to mongoose through my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to mongoose through my server but failing to do so.

I have already tried to put it into a try catch block but it says db.close or client.close is not a function. when I try to connect, I am getting an error "Unhandled promise rejection warning".

I would be glad if anyone could help me with this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const client = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/customercli', { 
useNewUrlParser: true });




// import the model
const Customer = require('./models/customer');


// Add customer
const addCustomer = (customer) => {
    Customer.create(customer).then(customer => {
        console.info("New Customer Added");
        client.close();
    });
}



// Find customer
const findCustomer = (name) => {
    //Make this case insensitive
    const search = new RegExp(name, 'i') // here lowercase i made it 
insensitive
    Customer.find({$or: [{firstname: search}, {lastname: search}]})
    .then(customer => {
        console.log(customer);
        console.log(`${customer.length} matches`);
        client.close();

    });
} 


//Export all methods
module.exports = {
    addCustomer,
    findCustomer
}
```

Comment: Could provide the exact error message ?

Comment: (node:18644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.close is not a function
    at Customer.find.then.customer (C:\customer-cli\index.js:33:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: Why are you closing your database connection every time ?

Comment: I am trying to build a command line interface, I have various commands like adding a customer, check the version, update the record for the customer, thus after every successful command execution I need to close the connection.

Comment: The error happens in `findCustomer`, try to `console.log(connect.isClosed?)` what do you get ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi Thank you, it was an error in `findcustomer` as well as the code `db.close()` doesn't close the mongoose connection. So to close the connection i used `mongoose.connecttion.close()`

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this by myself. The connection to mongoose through my server was not getting closed. so i replaced `db.close()` with `mongoose.connection.close()` and it worked just fine.